# Enable multi-core compiling in VS2010 debug mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How i can generate code using all cores on my computer in debug mode? I can generate code in release mode quiet fast but in debug it really slow.

Comment: Yes i meant compilation, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is unclear. Do you mean that your compilation is fast in Release, but slow in Debug? If so, then the solution is to set the Enable Multiprocessor Compilation option in the project settings, for the Debug target.

But if you're saying that the debug version of your application is slow, there is no magic option that will improve the speed to use all cores - you need to design your application to take advantage of multiple cores to begin with.